# Servers and sessions

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning about distributed TensorFlow applications, and I understand jobs, tasks, and servers. A server's target identifies its gRPC location, as in grpc://localhost:1234.

I don't understand what happens when you create a session with a server's target, as in the following code:

```
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
    ...
```

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) states that `server.target` identifies the session's execution engine. Another [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) says that the constructor creates a session on the server. This isn't clear to me. How exactly does a server's target affect the session's execution?